# Clojure seesaw application: How to change menubar title from "main"

Tags: macos, clojure, seesaw

In my standalone app written in clojure using seesaw to create the gui, and running under OSX, I get a menubar title "main". This appears to be the default for seesaw based programs. I see it in any of the tutorial examples available. Here is what mine looks like:

[image: The offending menu title]

I have tried renaming the (-main) function. The above image was taken with (-main) renamed to (-soulflyer) so it isn't choosing the title from that. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
(defn -soulflyer [& args]
  (invoke-later
   (let [f                (make-frame)
         details          (select f [:#details])
         image-pane       (select f [:#image])
         keyword-tree     (select f [:#tree])
8<---snip
```

Note this was run from the repl, the standalone version needs to have a -main function.

this is a section of the (make-frame) function:

```
(frame
 :title "Keyword Explorer"
 :size [1400 :by 800]
 :menubar
 (menubar :items
          [(menu :text "File" :items [])
           (menu :text "Edit" :items [])])
 :content
8<---snip
```

so the :title value only affects the title in the window not in the menubar.

Is there any way of changing this from clojure?

Edit: the project.clj file may be useful (rest of the code is at https://github.com/soulflyer/find-pics):

```
(defproject find-pics "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "Search for images containing specified keywords"
  :url "http://githube.com/soulflyer/find-pics"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [seesaw "1.4.5"]
                 [image-lib "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [com.novemberain/monger "3.0.1"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.3.3"]]
  :main find-pics.core
  :bin {:name "find-pics"
    :bin-path "~/bin"})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer is that you should add `:jvm-opts ["-Xdock:name=YOUR_APP_NAME"]` in the `project.clj` file.

Java Application in Mac OS X has an application menu. This application menu, by default, contains the full name of the main class as the title. If you want to change this, you can pass `-Xdock:name` VM argument like this.

```
java -Xdock:name=YOUR_APP_NAME ...
```

It seems that clojure function compiled into Java class. That's why the application menu appears as `main`, which is the same as `main` function name. Since you can not change the function name, you should add `-Xdock:name=YOUR_APP_NAME` to `:jvm-opts`.

For more detail, you can read the following document:

[OS X Integration for Java](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/07-NativePlatformIntegration/NativePlatformIntegration.html)